# Can I install ubuntu 18.04 in HP Ryzen 3 3520U laptop as Virtualbox?

Tags: laptop, hp, amd-ryzen, hybrid

Can I install ubuntu 18.04 in HP Ryzen 3 3520U laptop as Virtualbox/Virtual Machine? (It is a hybrid laptop with 256GB SSD/1TB HDD/Windows 10)

Comment: All anyone can tell you is try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Just go for it. Since you'd install in VM there should be no problems imho

Comment: It would be good if you could explain why there wouldn't be any problems...